# How do I get the testCaseResultId for a Azure DevOps API call

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I have a postman collection setup with all of the Azure DevOps API calls for "Tests".  I notice that a lot of the API calls you need the "testCaseResultId" in the endpoint.  I don't know how to get this id. I've looked at all of the responses and I don't see where it returns this.  Could someone please help!? I have 11 calls that need this.

Ex. GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/Results/{**testCaseResultId**}/Iterations/{iterationId}/actionresults/{actionPath}?api-version=5.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/test/Runs/%7BrunId%7D/Results/%7B**testCaseResultId**%7D/Iterations/%7BiterationId%7D/actionresults/%7BactionPath%7D?api-version=5.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of a **`testCaseResultId`**, you can try with the following ways:

1. Use the REST API "[**Results - List**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)" to list all the test results for a test run. From response body, you can see the **`testCaseResultId`** of each test results in the specified test run.

   [image]
2. View the **`testCaseResultId`** from the web page of Azure DevOps. In the project where the test run is in, navigate to '**Test Plans**' > '**Runs**'. Find the test run and click to open it. Select '**Test results**' tab, you can see the results of all the test cases executed in this run. Click one test case result to open it. On the address bar of the web browser, you can see the complete URL of this test case result. In the URL, you can see the **`testCaseResultId`** is contained.

   [image]

   [image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I am now able to see it.

Comment: Hi @user18806728, Glad that my answer can help you. Maybe, you can mark my answer as the solution of this ticket. This could also be helpful for other people who are looking for an answer for the similar questions. Thanks.